# Creating a custom formGroup validator using outside data

Tags: angular, angular-material2, formgroups

I'm still learning Angular 2+ and Material2 so if you could include some code snippets in your response I'd appreciate it.

I'm trying to create a form validator that uses a boolean value from my Angular component. The boolean is set from a function that queries my database and returns true if the submitted ID is unique.

However, I can't figure out how to get the validator to read that boolean. I'm also not quite sure how to handle custom validators and there seems to be little documentation on this.

Here's some code:

```
checkResult: boolean;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: ['', Validators.required],
    configuration: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
}


// Triggered when record is selected from table

viewRecord() {

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [formId, Validators.required, {validator: this.checkIdFn()}],
    configuration: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
}

checkID(): boolean {
  //queries database
  result: boolean
  this.checkResult = result
}

checkIdFn = (control: FormGroup) => {
  return this.checkResult ? null : { valid: false };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
id: [formId, [array of validators: Validators.required, MyValidator.something]],
```

`MyValidator.something` needs to be a function `(control: AbstractControl) -> ValidationErrors | null`

MyValidator.something can be your class function, but it would be better if you created a function that returns this validator `(any) -> ValidatorFn`

For example:

```
checkResult: boolean;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: ['', [Validators.required, this._myValidator()]],
    configuration: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
}

private _myValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return control.value && this.checkResult ? {error: 'error'} : null;
  }
}
```

You can easily make an async call inside ValidatorFn and defer validation result.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to initialize or import the "control" in the validator return statement? I'm getting the error: "Property 'control' does not exist on type 'ContractorsComponent' ". When I do the selected fix it adds `code` [x: string]: any; `code` but I get  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake. It should be `control` instead of `this.control`.

Comment: forgot to tag @Łukasz Szcześniak

Comment: @Richard By the way, you don't need to use state variable checkResult. Avoid unnecessary state.

Comment: Thanks, but I made that change and the custom validator seems to not be doing anything. I even changed the return statement to `control.value && false ? ...` but the error still doesn't show on the view. The error displays when I leave the field empty (since it's required). I'm using `<mat-error *ngIf="!form.get('id').valid">error</mat-error>` in my view. **EDIT** I'm actually calling the function instead of checkResult, that was just for clarity.

Comment: @Richard To 'throw' an error, you have to return an object, so it would rather be `return {error: 'error'};`. Also, field has to be 'touched' before it will be considered as invalid. Read https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Comment: @Richard Also, did you bind your html form to formGroup? And did you bind field?